# Search option with specific text words with multiple inputs [=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A1)),"Y"," ")]

Tags: excel

[image]

Search option with specific text words with multiple inputs

[image]

Column A contains text trying to search a specific test in a cell prints output Y/N

A1 cell contain text apple applying formula in B1 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A1)),"Y"," ") output prints "Y" as expected.

A2 Cell contain text [apples][3] applying the same formula in B2 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A2)),"Y"," ")output still shows "Y" How to get it printed as "N"

A3 Cell contain text apple,apples applying the same formula in B3 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A3)),"Y"," ") output prints "Y" as expected.

A4 cell contain text apples,apple applying the same formula in B4 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A4)),"Y"," ")output prints "Y" as expected.

Now the query is how to get printed as "N" or Blank if "apple" is not exist in cell.

Answer (score 0):

If your words are always separated by a comma as shown in your provided sample data, this should work for you to find an exact match.  Put in cell B1 and copy down:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",apple,",","&A1&",")),"Y","N")
```